# Separating Content from Design in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates

I'm not a super-experienced Wordpress guy, but I generally know what I'm doing, and have been programming for years.

I'm in the middle of building a fairly simple Wordpress site, but lots of posts will be added in the future by the client.

It suddenly dawned on me that all my posts are static, so if changes in design are needed they will need to be applied manually across many pages.

I've searched Google but to no avail. What I need is a plugin or method that allows me to have templates for my posts, into which the unique content for each page are added. Then, if design changes are needed, I simply edit the template and the design will change instantly across all the pages using this template.

I've found plugins which seem to offer post templates, but all they seem to do is create a new post with a pre-made design, but do not make it possible to make changes to that design which are reflected across all the posts that use that template. Maybe I'm missing something simple here, as I can't be the only WP author who wants to achieve this?

I'm not talking about dynamic content. ie I have no need to pull constantly updated data like weather or prices from an API. The content is hand-written for each page, but I would like to separate it from the design, so if design changes are needed they can be made only once from some kind of post template manager, and not individually on each page.

Actually, I'm already using the simple post-snippets plugin, and I realise that I could use this or something similar to achieve my aim, but I don't think this would be very user-friendly for non-technical authors. Instead, it would be ideal if I had a set of custom fields under each post which the authors filled in, and the content was then taken from there and inserted in the page's template.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you should be able to change the design just using CSS selectors. Of course that may have its limitations but there is never a design that fits it all.

For bigger changes you will need to change the WordPress template.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to clarify a little more. I only want to change the design around the content within posts. For example I have a post for each person in the team. The layout is created with the Fusion builder in Avada theme, which creates the layout (columns, image frames etc etc) with shortcodes, but in each of these posts there are only 2 unique pieces of data: the photo url and the description of this person. Imagine the client then decides they want to make the photo appear bigger, which means I have to hand-edit all of these posts.

Comment: That is not necessarily true, you may set the width and height of an image with CSS code so you may change them all just modifying the CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research and poking around, this is what I've come up with.

Install the 'Advanced Custom Fields' and 'Custom Post Templates' plugins , although neither are strictly necessary.

Create a group of custom fields which defines the unique data (URL, media selector etc) for each post.

Most importantly, create a new custom post template following the instructions for the 'Custom Post Templates' plugin. In this template remove the line that outputs the post content (the_content()), and replace it with code that outputs all the shortcodes or whatever for this page type, with placeholders string replaced with the values of the custom variables for that post. Then (in my case) I do something like do_shortcode($page_template) to correctly output the correct content for that page.

I create a new post, leaving the content field completely empty, and filling in the custom field's values as required. Also, you must choose the post template, so it matches the new custom template you create.

```
$v=get_post_custom_values("image_url")[0];//gets the id of the post which contains the image

$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($v, 'medium')[0]; //get the image (URL?) from the reference

$page_template='[one_third last="no" spacing="yes" background_color="" background_image="" background_repeat="no-repeat" background_position="left top" border_size="2px" border_color="#eaeaea" border_style="solid" padding="20px" class="" id=""][imageframe lightbox="no" style_type="none" bordercolor="" bordersize="0px" borderradius="0" stylecolor="" align="none" link="" linktarget="_self" animation_type="0" animation_direction="down" animation_speed="0.1" class="" id=""] <img src="#image_url#" alt="" />[/imageframe][fusion_text]<a href="mailto:#personal_email#">Email Me</a> | <a href="#personal_website_url#" target="_blank">Website</a>[/fusion_text][/one_third][two_third last="yes" spacing="yes" background_color="" background_image="" background_repeat="no-repeat" background_position="left top" border_size="0px" border_color="" border_style="" padding="" class="" id=""][fusion_text]#main_text_html#[/fusion_text][/two_third]';

$page_template=str_replace ( "#image_url#" , $image_url , $page_template );
echo do_shortcode($page_template);
```

The code above contains the page template hard-coded into the $page_template variable, but it could also be loaded by referencing the id of the post which is acting as the template.

This code currently only inserts the correct image URL. Once it's finished it will also insert the personal email link, website link, and main text.